# Stop Replica Set MongoDB

Tags: linux, mongodb

The command to start a Replica Set in the MongoDB Shell is rs.initiate().

What is the opposite of this command. How do I stop the replica set?

There are commands to reconfigure the set or remove members but no way that I know off to remove the last member and therefore destroy the Replica Set.

Comment: The most common way is to just stop the `mongod`, since you must restart the `mongod` without the replica option to actually stop it from trying to use the replica set.

Comment: When I start mongo after doing that it give me this warning: "WARNING: mongod started without --replSet yet 1 documents are present in local.system.replset". How do I clean this up?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10953752/490018

Comment: See here for a complete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544713/encountered-a-mongodb-warning-after-converting-a-replica-set-to-stand-alone-serv/34920289#34920289

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It all depends on what your goal is. If you want to reuse the existing `mongod` as a standalone server rather than a replica set member then the steps to do that would be:

1. Restart mongod process without `--replSet` argument.
2. Drop the local database:

   ```
   use local;
   db.dropDatabase();
   ```

Comment: "errmsg" : "Cannot drop 'local' database while replication is active"

Comment: you have to restart server without --replSet flag before you can drop local.

Comment: MongoDB 2.6 error log claims you only need to empty local.system.replset, not dropping the whole local DB. So, `use local` , then `db.system.replset.remove({})`.

Comment: if you drop local then you are not depending on version specific internals of implementation.  All replication information will always be stored in local DB.

Answer (score 11):

I just have this issue in production. @maganap's (Mar 15) comment saved my bacon!

Using mongodb 3.2.10, no need to dump the oplog, just do this on the first member:

```
use local
db.system.replset.remove({})
```

Then restart the member. It'll now still have it's oplog, and it's data. Just run:

```
rs.initiate()
rs.reconfig(conf)
```

Where conf is the new conf. Then on each of the other members, just run the trashing of the replset data above and restart them. When they start they'll join the set.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to mongo shell on Secondary servers
2. Stop the secondary servers by using below command:

- `> use admin`
- `> db.shutdownServer()`

3. Go to Linux shell- on secondary servers and type below command:

- `sudo service mongod stop`

For more information, Please check the below link:

http://www.tutorial-points.com/2016/03/stopping-and-starting-mongodb.html