# Encountered a MongoDB warning after converting a replica set to stand alone server

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

I encountered the following warning after converting a mongodb replica set to a stand alone server. I did rs.remove('host') and removed the replSet arguments when starting the mongo db.

```
[root@sam ~]# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
Tue Jul  9 17:18:46.076 [initandlisten] 
Tue Jul  9 17:18:46.076 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: mongod started without --replSet yet 1 documents are present in local.system.replset
Tue Jul  9 17:18:46.077 [initandlisten] **          Restart with --replSet unless you are doing maintenance and no other clients are connected.
Tue Jul  9 17:18:46.077 [initandlisten] **          The TTL collection monitor will not start because of this.
Tue Jul  9 17:18:46.077 [initandlisten] **          For more info see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/ttlcollections
Tue Jul  9 17:18:46.077 [initandlisten] 
>
```

Please help. Need to fixed it immediately. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

The local database contains replica set information among other things.  You can drop the local database without ill effect.
Use the following comments to drop the local database.

```
use local
db.dropDatabase()
```

The warning messages should go away after restarting mongod

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and the message still appears. I'm also getting the following message: `> use local
switched to db local
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "local", "ok" : 1 }
> rs.status()
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not running with --replSet" }`

Answer (score 8):

```
use local;
db.dropDatabase();
db.system.replset.remove ({});
```

Quit the mongo shell .. restart service just in case "service mongod restart"

```
mongo --host bind_ip --port bind_port
```