# MongoDB: Stop from storing replica set settings

Tags: mongodb

I have a local mongo database that's being populated by a script which will run for the next few days.

When it'll be done, I'm expecting its size to be quite substantial, so I want mongo to stop storing replica sets (or whatever is it doing in that database called "local"), because this is just a pet project, the database is local. I won't have any clients so I don't need replication and the database will only be used for reads after the initial data is inserted. It has the same size as my database so it's a waste of space.

I found this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800461/stop-replica-set-mongodb) where they just basically say to drop the local database and I did that but, every time I'm starting mongod, it's there again (and I'm not starting mongod with --replSet. Mongod doesn't even recognize that flag, btw). Could you please tell me how do I stop mongod from generating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running mongod as a standalone (no --replSet option) means you won't store oplog entries or replica set related information.

The local database will be created. The size of the local database should remain static in this case. The contents should be 2 collections:

**startup_log** which holds static information about your mongod instance, including version, start time and startup options.

**system.indexes** which contains index definitions for the collections in this database. In this case it would have a single entry defining the _id index for startup_log.

To confirm yourself that these are the only 2 collections run the following from the mongo shell:

```
use local;
show collections;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe it should remain static, but it's size seems to always follow my db's (ngrams). See: `> show dbs
admin   (empty)
local   0.078GB
ngrams  0.078GB
> 
`. So, how do I stop mongo from generating it?

Comment: The local db size won't follow your ngrams DB size. MongoDB preallocates data files so your first file will be the same size. As ngrams grows past the initial size new files will be allocated (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database). If you want smaller data file size (but more data files if you grow past them) you can try the --smallfiles argument to mongod.

Comment: OK, thanks for the refference and sorry for the delay.